# Como dividir os elementos de uma matriz pela média da sua coluna

Tags: r, divisão, matriz

Preciso dividir os elementos de uma matriz pela respectiva média da sua coluna, como posso fazer isto, existe alguma função para realizar esta simples operação?

Considerando a matriz:

```
  > A <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)
  > A
       [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4]
  [1,]    1    5    9   13
  [2,]    2    6   10   14
  [3,]    3    7   11   15
  [4,]    4    8   12   16
```

E a média de cada coluna no vetor:

```
 > MediacolA <- colMeans(A)
 > MediacolA
 [1]  2.5  6.5 10.5 14.5
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provavelmente isto resolve seu problema

```
A <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)
apply(A, 2, function(x) x/mean(x))
```

A segunda linha pode ser descrita como "Aplicar a função a segunda dimensão(colunas) da matriz"

== Edit ==

Também existe a seguinte opção que retorna o mesmo resultado

```
sweep(A, 2, colMeans(A), "/", FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

Uma alternativa é replicar as médias para criar uma matriz com o mesmo tamanho da matriz original, e depois dividir a original por ela. O código abaixo mostra uma forma como isso pode ser feito.

```
> A <- matrix(1:16, ncol = 4)
> MediacolA <- colMeans(A)
> repMedia <- rep(MediacolA, length(A) / length(MediacolA))
> A / t(matrix(repMedia, ncol=4))
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  0.4 0.7692308 0.8571429 0.8965517
[2,]  0.8 0.9230769 0.9523810 0.9655172
[3,]  1.2 1.0769231 1.0476190 1.0344828
[4,]  1.6 1.2307692 1.1428571 1.1034483
```

Answer (score 1):

Este tipo de operação em matrizes pode ser realizada com a função `scale`, que serve justamente para redimensionar as colunas de uma matriz.

O default desta função é subtrair cada coluna de sua média, depois dividir pelo desvio padrão. Como o que você quer é diferente, temos que mudar os argumentos, fornecendo o vetor que deve ser utilizado no redimensionamento (`scale = colMeans(A)`), e desativando a centralização (`center = FALSE`), da seguinte forma:

```
> scale(A, scale = colMeans(A), center = FALSE)
     [,1]      [,2]      [,3]      [,4]
[1,]  0.4 0.7692308 0.8571429 0.8965517
[2,]  0.8 0.9230769 0.9523810 0.9655172
[3,]  1.2 1.0769231 1.0476190 1.0344828
[4,]  1.6 1.2307692 1.1428571 1.1034483
attr(,"scaled:scale")
[1]  2.5  6.5 10.5 14.5
```

Não se preocupe com o `attr` que aparece no final, é apenas um registro do vetor utilizado em scale, mas ele é ignorado se você fizer qualquer operação com a matriz depois.